# Functions and arrays in for loop creating error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, momentjs

I'm using a JS library called moment.js to find and eliminate events with a wide gap between start_time and stop_time.  I keep getting this error though--

TypeError: moment(...) is null
var stopmoment1 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("YYYY");

AAA!!!

> for (var x = 0; x < data.page_size; x++) {
>
> ```
> var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
>   data.events.event[x]['latitude'],
>   data.events.event[x]['longitude']);
> ```
>
> // the year is returned in the console
>
> console.log(moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("YYYY"));
>
> // but here it says moment returns null
>
> var startmoment1 =
>   moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("YYYY");
>   var startmoment2 = moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("MM");
>   var startmoment3 = moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("DD");
>
> var startmoment = moment([startmoment1,startmoment2,startmoment3]);
>
> var stopmoment1 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("YYYY");
>   var stopmoment2 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("MM");
>   var stopmoment3 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("DD");
>
> var stopmoment = moment([stopmoment1,stopmoment2,stopmoment3]);
>
> if (startmoment.diff(stopmoment, 'days') > 7) {   }   else{
>
> ```
> if (moment().format("YYYYMMDD") == moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("YYYYMMDD")) {
>
>   marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
>     position: position,
>     map: map,
>     icon: image
>   }));
>
>   marker[x].x = x;//make the marker aware of its own index
>
>   google.maps.event.addListener(marker[x], 'click', function() {
>     var div = document.createElement('div');
>     div.setAttribute("id", "tabs-min");
>     div.innerHTML = content[this.x];
>     $(div).tabs();
>     infowindow.setContent(div); 
>     infowindow.open(map, this);
>   });
>
>
> } else {
>   marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
>     position: position,
>     map: map,
>     icon: image1
>   }));
>
>   marker[x].x = x;//make the marker aware of its own index
>
>   google.maps.event.addListener(marker[x], 'click', function() {
>     var div = document.createElement('div');
>     div.setAttribute("id", "tabs-min");
>     div.innerHTML = content[this.x];
>     $(div).tabs();
>     infowindow.setContent(div); 
>     infowindow.open(map, this);
>   });   }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood, the line `var stopmoment1 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("YYYY");` is giving you an error and it's not in an event handler function set within a loop? As Kristof suggested maybe console.log some things. In Firefox you can press control+shift+k and in Chrome it's F12 to open the console (IE has console but logs [object Ojbect] 90% of the time) then you can start logging some things like `console.log("moment is:", moment)` and `console.log("stop time is:",data.events.event[x].stop_time)`

Comment: I've updated my answer, try adding the eventListeners variable in global scope and replace the with the code I posted. Re declaring event listeners every time is repeating your code (copy paste) instead it's better to re use an existing function. And with this way you can limit the amount of variables available to the closure. It has some console.log statements in there that could give you a hint on what's going on.

Comment: Why you have this: `for (var x = 0; x < data.page_size; x++) {` why not this: `for (var x = 0; x < data.event.length; x++) {`

Comment: I think I didn't know .length property at the time.  page_size is part of the json response and equivalent to length, so I chose that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in loops, can you spot the differences in the following 2 code snippets?

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);//logs 10 every time
  },10);
}
```

And the correct one

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  setTimeout((function(i){
    return function(){
      console.log(i);//logs 0,1,2,3,4...
    };
  }(i)),10);
}
```

**[update]**

I have re formatted your code, removed repeating code, added logs, moved even listeners in a separate object so you can call it and pass variables needed for closure without trapping possibly big variables in there and have a more robust event handler attachment within loops:

```
var eventListeners={
  markerClick:function(myContent){
      return function(e) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", "tabs-min");
        div.innerHTML = myContent;
        $(div).tabs();
        infowindow.setContent(div);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      };
    }
};

for (var x = 0; x < data.event.length; x++) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
          data.events.event[x]['latitude'],
          data.events.event[x]['longitude']);

  console.log("moment is:",moment);
  console.log("data.events is:", data.events);
  console.log("x is:",x);
  console.log("event at x is:",data.events.event[x]);
  console.log("start time is:",data.events.event[x].start_time);
  var startmoment1 = moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("YYYY");
  var startmoment2 = moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("MM");
  var startmoment3 = moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("DD");
  var startmoment = moment([startmoment1, startmoment2, startmoment3]);

  var stopmoment1 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("YYYY");
  var stopmoment2 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("MM");
  var stopmoment3 = moment(data.events.event[x].stop_time).format("DD");
  var stopmoment = moment([stopmoment1, stopmoment2, stopmoment3]);

  if (!(startmoment.diff(stopmoment, 'days') > 7)) {
    marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
  //no need for the if statement, only thing different is the image
  //but you are repating a lot of other code like adding and defining the handler
      icon: (moment().format("YYYYMMDD") ===
              moment(data.events.event[x].start_time).format("YYYYMMDD")) ?
              image : image1
    }));
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[x], 'click', 
      eventListeners.markerClick(content[x]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks!  I see what's happening now.  When x=3, event stop time is null which trips up the moment function.

Answer (score 1):

Do an alert or console.writeline or debug it to find out the value of data.events.event[x].stop_time.
You are probably passing undefined or an empty string into the moment function which causes the exception.